# $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln\, n)^2}$ c0nvergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln\, n)^2}$$

The series converge?

Please verify my solution below

Comment: Surely because $\ln 1 = 0$, the series won't converge because at $n=1$ we have an indeterminate form? Also, even if we were to change the bottom limit to $n=2$, the series won't converge for the reasons given in the comments below.

Comment: Should be n=2, fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It diverges. See that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln^2(n)}=\infty$$ Infact the power of $n$ is $\frac{1}{2}\leq1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/2}u_n=\infty$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{(ln\, n)^{2}}\iff n\geq(ln\, n)^{2}\iff ln\, n\leq\sqrt{n}\iff n\leq e^{\sqrt{n}}$

$\begin{cases}(e^{\sqrt{n}})'>(n)'\\\text{for  } n=1\,\,\,\,
  e^{1}>1\end{cases}$

so from comparison test, the series diverge

Comment: Does $\sum 1/n$ converge?

Comment: Perfect until the last *word*: the series $\sum\limits_n\frac1n$ *diverges* hence by comparison...

Comment: That's a typo of course. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Cauchy Condensation Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln k)^{2}} \text{converges} \iff \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{(\ln 2^k)^{2}} \text{converges}$$

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{(\ln 2^k)^{2}} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{(\ln 2^k)(\ln 2^k)}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{k^2(\ln 2)(\ln 2)}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{k^2(\ln 2)^2} \text{(diverges)}$$

So the original series diverges.

Comment: :very nice proof